# Unstable multimeter current readings

Tags: dc, current-measurement, multimeter

I have Fluke 17B+ DMM.

When trying to measure DC current, the readings are constantly fluctuating.

I tried first with a 9V 1A AC-DC wall adapter and the readings were jumping between 0.485 to 0.300 and then down to 0 A. This pattern keeps on repeating. When I used the same DC source but with a 5V buck converter I get a stable 1A reading. I have tried with different probes and another similar DC adapter but this behavior persists. Unless I use a regulator or measure current in circuit, the current measurement is not stable. Is my DMM gone bad, or could there be some other issue?

Comment: How are you measuring current? Using current measurement mode and sticking the multimeter probes directly to wall adapter output?

Comment: What load were you using?

Comment: You are aware that the current should be measured in a *circuit*? Not on a power supply?

Comment: Yes I was "Using current measurement mode and sticking the multimeter probes directly to wall adapter output? " May be it's silly or too naïve of me to try to measure whether the AC-DC adapter outputs it's rated amperage

Comment: @EugeneSh. I thought the resistor inside should be enough to create a "circuit". Am I mistaken in my approach?

Comment: @ErikR as I said in the comment above I thought the resistor in the DMM would serve as a load.

Comment: No. The internal resistance of an amperemeter is very low, intentionally to make it not interfere with a circuit measured. You have probably fried your device or blown its fuse.  Anyway, what is the point of measuring what you are trying to measure? The current is meaningful only in a context of specific circuit.

Comment: Sometimes I have become driven geekly crazy by auto-ranging multimeters that cannot settle down to one range. Can you try turning off *auto-ranging*?

Comment: @EugeneSh.  So stupid of me :( I was just suspecting that also but the DMM still measures the current correctly in circuit or with a regulator. Should I still replace the fuses?

Comment: @Transistor yes that's exactly the way I was unintentionally trying to fry my DMM :(

Comment: @Zaffresky You can try testing it in a simple circuit where you can calculate the current. Or you can visually examine the fuse.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was trying to verify if the DC adapter can deliver it's full rated amperage

Comment: @Zaffresky By connecting the amperemeter to the power supply you are essentially shorting it. If the PS can't deliver enough current to fry your DMM, then you are lucky and might even read the "correct" result. When you see the current jumping, it is likely some internal PS short protection kicking in and turning the power on and off.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I hope that is the case and the fuses survived. I will visually inspect and try to verify it in circuit measurements.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback :)

Comment: I'll be stunned if you didn't blow a fuse in your meter.....